# How to get Client Geolocation Like Google search?

Tags: jquery, html, google-api, geolocation, region

I want to know, How can i get location like google?

As you can see in this picture:[image: Google Search GeoLocation]
Google does announcing the location exactly as Country - Province/State - City/Town - District/Block
I read many about GeoLocation and Google Api but i can't understand them well.
So Is there any body, Who can help me with a sample html/jquery code
Please attention i don't need Latitude/Attitude or some else same like them.

Comment: start reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: @madalinivascu I read it before, Unfortunately it's like others, just get location as latitude/longitude . As i asked, I Want Full Region/City/District Information like google search

Comment: @madalinivascu My Dear Friend, AS I ASKED in question 

"Who can help me with a sample html/jquery code"

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Comment: what you are searching for is called reverse geocoding and you need to do a ajax request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY with your api key and your latlng values see:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Code Sample

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```